# how to go to the end of method with shortcuts in XCODE?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will go to the end of a long function definition from the beginning of the function?

Answer (score 1):

The list of possible actions that can be done by shortcuts in Xcode is available at: **Xcode - Preferences... - Key Bindings**. I didn't find what you want by checking the "Selection" section which contains all the things about selecting and moving.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog, it lists all the shortcuts for Xcode. I don't believe it has what you want though. http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html